# show that sequence $\{(-1)^n\Upsilon_n\}$ is convergent and strictly decreasing

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sequences-and-series, bernoulli-numbers

**Edit**: Few years ago, I have posted my claim on $\Upsilon$ function regarding prime number but recently I have observed, last observation turns false that's way, (by putting $\Upsilon$ value in programming). In this Edit, erase the last observation and come up with new claim which one is always in my mind from beginning, it says sequence $\{(-1)^n\Upsilon_n\}$ is convergent and strictly decreasing.

---

The idea of ​​$\Upsilon$ number comes from my [power sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265732/647719) and negative values of zeta function

**Definition**  let $m$ be a non-negative integer
$$\zeta(-m)=(-1)^{m}\frac{B_{m+1}}{m+1}=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \Upsilon_b\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$$

so we can calculate values of $\Upsilon_b$ , if we substitute value $\zeta (0)=-1/2$ gives $\Upsilon_1=-1/2$.

Again we can calculate next value using or substituting previous values of $\Upsilon_b$.

First values are
$$\begin{align*}
\Upsilon_1&=-\frac{ 1}{2},\\
\Upsilon_2&=\frac{ 5}{12},\\
\Upsilon_3&=-\frac{ 3}{8},\\
\Upsilon_4&=\frac{ 251}{720},\\
\Upsilon_5&=-\frac{ 95}{288},\\
\Upsilon_6&=\frac{ 19087}{60480},\\
\Upsilon_7&=-\frac {5257}{17280}.
\end{align*}$$

> > **Updated claim:** sequence $\{(-1)^n\Upsilon_n\}$ is convergent and strictly decreasing.

In compact form

Let [$D_{m,b}=\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3321413/647719)

So $D_{m,m+1}=m!$

$$\Upsilon_{m+1}=\frac{(-1)^{m}B_{m+1}-(m+1)(\Upsilon_1 D_{m,1}+\Upsilon_2 D_{m,2}+\cdots+\Upsilon_m D_{m,m})}{(m+1)!}$$

Graph for $n$ vs $(-1)^n\Upsilon_n$

[image]

python code

```
from fractions import Fraction as Fr
def factorial(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)

def combination(m,k):
    if k <= m:
        return factorial(m)/(factorial(k) * factorial(m - k))
    else:
        return 0
    
def  D(m,b):
    k = 0
    for i in range(b):
         k += (-1)**i*(b-i)**m*combination(b-1,i)
    return int(k)  

def B(n):
    A = [0] * (n+1)
    for m in range(n+1):
        A[m] = Fr(1, m+1)
        for j in range(m, 0, -1):
          A[j-1] = j*(A[j-1] - A[j])
    return A[0] # (which is Bn)

def Y(n):
    s = 0
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return Fr(-0.5)
    else:
        for i in range(1,n):
            s += Y(i)*D(n-1,i)
        s1 = ((-1)**(n-1)*B(n)-n*s)/factorial(n)
        return s1
```